# Copy network file from a Linux host to my Linux server using PHP

Tags: php, linux, network-programming

I am trying to retrieve a network file from an OpenSUSE 13.1 Host to my OpenSUSE 13.2 Webserver, but I don't seem to have any success.

First I check if target directory is a directory:

```
$path = "\\\\192.168.xxx.xxx\\public";
if(is_dir($path)){ // returns FALSE every time.
  return true;
}
```

In this case the function is_dir() returns FALSE, although the folder exists and has 777 permisions, the IP is correct, and the computer is turned ON.
I have tried all the combinations of formatting the network path, including  `$path = "smb://192.168.xxx.xxx/public";` witch returns an error

> Unable to find the wrapper "smb" - did you forget to enable it when
>   you configured PHP?

Could someone tell me what I am missing?

Would it work the same through a OpenVPN with my Centos 6 webserver and an Ubuntu 14 host?

Comment: Have you shared your `public` directory somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has no built-in Samba support on the Linux platform. You will need to mount the remote share (requires superuser-equivalent access) and access its contents like a local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, that's an ideea. I have also done the copy by using `ssh2_scp_recv()`  function.

Comment: @candino Yes, that is a possibility if you have SSH access to the target machine. Note though, that SSH (both SCP and SFTP) is very inefficient in handling lots of files (lot of synchronous set-up before each file), so if you expect heavy operations, mounting would be much more efficient (will utilize caching for example).